# Java Eclipse - clicker counter - not incrementing

Tags: eclipse

Very simple as am very new to java Eclipse. Using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Helios Service Release 2. Created a button and Label. Using this button to increment a the value by 1 at time but nothing is happening. Not sure why its not. Please can someone have a look at. I don't think I am too far off then again I maybr. Thanks in advance...

```
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import javax.swing.*;

   public class First 
   {
       //int counter = 0; //  tried it here -> unsuccesfull
       // static int counter = 0; //  tried it here -> unsuccesfull

      public static void main (String [] args){
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("att");
      frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setSize(500,500);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  frame.add(panel);

      JButton button = new  JButton("+");
      frame.add(panel);
  panel.add(button);

      JLabel label = new JLabel("1");
  frame.add(panel);
  panel.add(label);

      // int counter = 0; // tried it here -> unsuccesfull

      // final int counter = 0; // tried it here -> unsuccesfull. Getting error
      // "The final local variable counter cannot be assigned, since it is 
      // defined in an enclosing type" *

      button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
      {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {
          label1.setVisible(true);
      int counter = 0;
      counter = counter + 1 ; // *
    }
 }
);
```

Modified the code and placed the int variable after class declartion and jut after button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() method header and no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting to 0 the `counter` everytime the button is been clicked.

If what you want is to keep track of the amount of times the button has been clicked then you want to declare the variable out of the listener. Otherwise, everytime you click on the button `counter` will always be declared and set to 0. Hence, it will not increment in the way you expect.

You should try something like this:

```
  static int counter = 0; 

  public static void main (String [] args){
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("att");
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setSize(500,500);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  frame.add(panel);

  JButton button1 = new  JButton("+");
  frame.add(panel);
  panel.add(button1);

  final JLabel label1 = new JLabel("0");
  frame.add(panel);
  panel.add(label1);

  button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
 {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
 {
      label1.setVisible(true);         
      counter += 1 ; // *
      label1.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
 }
 }
 );
```

Comment: Now you have to set counter to the label

Comment: Additionally, you were not assigning the value to the label. See the edited version and it should work. Keep in mind that counter is a static variable which basically means the value is common to all instances of a particular class. if you want to digg into the topic check [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: Haa, yes, I see. I was looking at my  label1.Text = counter.ToString(); in C#. As you have kindly provided, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this fragment of your code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {
          label1.setVisible(true);
      int counter = 0; // you are setting variable to 0
      counter = counter + 1 ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong, but your counter variable will always be 1, since it's been initialized just before the increment operation.

Move its initialization like that:

```
public class First {
    int counter = 0;
```

and let counter = counter + 1 stay where it is now